# SQL query to get all data from a table that is less than 30 days old

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with 4 fields,

```
id - INT Primary
description - TEXT
postdate - DATETIME
username - TEXT
```

I was able to connect to database

I am inserting data 1 row at a time:

```
"INSERT INTO userdata(description, postdate, username) VALUES('test', now(), 'test2')"
```

I would like to run a query, or multiple queries to retrieve all the rows where `postdate` is less than 30 days from current time

I'm new to SQL, does the `SELECT` query only return 1 cell from the table at a time? Can I get it to return the whole row so I can parse it? Can I get it to return multiple rows with all of the data? Or do I need to do multiple queries? How would be that be done, do I need to run the query in a loop until nothing is returned?

Can someone help me figure out how to write this query that would either get the whole row or multiple rows? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the SELECT query only return 1 cell from the table at a time? Can I get it to return the whole row so I can parse it?

---

SQL can return a lot of data at a time.

```
SELECT id, description, postdate, username 
FROM `MyTable`
WHERE postdate < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```